# How can I listen to tags in stackoverflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions, tags

Is there a way I could "listen" (maybe get an e-mail a message in my stackoverflow inbox) to some tags, so when a question is added this tag I can answer it quickly?

Comment: You can use the Interesting Tags section at the right of the frontpage or subscribe to tag RSS feeds.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe you can get an e-mail, but you can subscribe to an RSS feed for a set of 1 or more tags:

Here's the one for questions tagged with both `[php]` and `[jquery]`:

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=php+jquery

If you're browsing questions by tag, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-interface), there is a link at the bottom of each page with a URL to the RSS feed for that set of questions.